# Pattern Matching in Augmented Reality 

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching, augmented-reality

I'm planning to build an Android App. based on *Augmented Reality*. I googled it and also searched on SO, but have not found anything very much helpful.

What I want to do is when application is launched, it will start it's camera and initiate the scanning of the pattern. If at any instance the pattern matches with the predefined pattern present in local database, it should perform a specific action.

For eg. On app launch, camera is started. While scanning, it came across `stackoverflow` logo(**image 1 as shown below**) and assuming that `stackoverflow` logo is already present in database(**image 2 as shown below**) in binary pattern format, both pattern should be matched and some specific task is performed, for instance `stackoverflow.com` should be loaded.

I referred [this tutorial]:[1](http://code.google.com/p/andar/wiki/HowToBuildApplicationsBasedOnAndAR) it and when I implemented the same, camera gets started with a **green cube** frequently appearing and disappearing. What functionality that **green cube** provides?

How do I capture the pattern from camera's focused area and how do I match it with another pattern?

I know I'm bit unclear in this question but as I'm new to android development, any suggestion would be of great help.

---

**image 1(currently focused by camera)**

[image: screen]

---

**image 2(present in database in binary pattern format)**

[image: screen]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the Qualcomm AR SDK:

https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality

Although mostly targeted at AR applications with 3d content tracked over a marker, you can also use it to recognize images (if they are complex enough) of up to about 60 (if they are different enough).

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't got that completely.

What actually it does? Does it captures the pattern or performs the pattern matching or anything else?

Comment: It can be used to do the actual pattern matching

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do image tracking. There are several different types of tracking you can use to match a pattern. This [tutorial](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tracking-configuration/optical-tracking-technologies/markerless/) explains the different ones, but I linked you specifically to the markerless tracking since that seems to fit your logo example.

However, if you want to quickly "build" the function of scanning and simply opening a link, I'd use [this](http://dev.metaio.com/creator/getting-started/). It's called the Creator and made by metaio (they also make an sdk and have an api for their browser Junaio that allows you to do this).  It says its for publishers but it's just a drag and drop UI for making simple AR. You don't even have to code.

Hope this helps.